# What analogue input voltages does this ADC understand?

Tags: adc

I have a 14-bit [ADC](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD9248.pdf) for which I do not know what the "accepted input voltage" is.

The datasheet specifies that there are "out-of-range" signals, but I cannot find what the range is. What is the range of my ADC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can understand from the datasheet, the input voltage can be defined from 1V p-p to 2V p-p

Span = 2 × (REFT − REFB) = 2 × VREF   --  (From page 17)

VREF = 0.5 × (1 + R2/R1)   --  (From pages 20/21)

Comment: Thanks. What exactly does `V p-p` mean?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken p-p means peak to peak.